# Does a true polymorphed familiar retain the mechanical benefits of a familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, polymorph

If I use [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) as an Arcane Trickster Rogue, then have a high level wizard cast (concentration) *[true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* on said familiar to turn them into a [homunculus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/homunculus), would the familiar still retain the mechanical benefits granted by the spell?

Specifically,

- Would the Homunculus be telepathically linked to my Rogue? (anywhere on the same plane of existence)?
- Would the familiar still "deliver a spell with a range of touch" (eg use mage hand to pick pockets in a different city)?

Comment: I made some edits to your question. Do they still represent what you are trying to ask?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose looks good

Comment: Also what do you mean by "eg use mage hand to pick pockets in a different city"? Do you mean that the humunculus-familiar attempts to pick pockets with mage hand while being in a different city from the rogue?

Comment: From my understanding, the familiar is just a conduit of the spell ... not the caster itself.  Could I use this effect to cast mage hand while outside of the normal range presented by the familiar.

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction: Reread the last paragraph of the *find familiar* spell description: "Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use your attack modifier for the roll."

Comment: @ravery, homunculus have inf telepathic range  ... hence why I would want to poly

Comment: @ravery don't answer in the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Familiars retain the benefits of being a familiar even when *true polymorphed*

Nothing about *true polymorph* cancels the effects of the *find familiar* spell. The benefits of *find familiar* such as telepathy and the ability to deliver touch spells are not statistics of the familiar (they aren't listed in their statblock) and thus aren't replaced by *true polymorph*.

Remember the general policy for two spells interacting as stated by [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1011745397767749632):

> Spell A doesn't cancel spell B unless the text of spell A says it does.

#### Transforming into a homunculus will give you telepathy while on the same plane

The statblock for the homunculus says:

> **Telepathic Bond.** While the homunculus is on the same plane of existence as its master, it can magically convey what it senses to its master, and the two can communicate telepathically.

While not canceling the effects of *find familiar*, in this case *true polymorph* would add to the familiar's abilities because it is changing the underlying creature's natural abilities. This is not changing anything about the *find familiar* spell's effects though only adding an ability to the familiar itself.

#### You cannot gain infinite range for casting spells through your familiar

As stated in the first section, nothing about *true polymorph* cancels the effects of the *find familiar* spell. Thus, you can still cast spells through your homunculus familiar because *find familiar* says:

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it.

Note that the range, 100 feet, has nothing to do with telepathy. It is a separate range listed in a separate part of the spell description. Thus, increasing the range at which you can communicate with the familiar telepathically will do nothing to increase the range at which they can deliver spells. Nothing about *true polymorph* or the statblock for a humunculus specifically states that they increase the range for familiars to deliver touch spells, so they do not.

Also, note that *mage hand* is not a touch spell so it cannot be delivered through a familiar regardless. (thanks @v2blast)

Comment: Ok so casting spells through the it would still work ... I would just have to be in the 100 feet range. So still a good pick pocket minion, just not w/ inf range.

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction correct!

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction: Note that *mage hand* isn't a touch range spell, though, and can't be delivered through your familiar.

Comment: @V2Blast good point